# Regex match numerical range

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, xval

I am trying to write a simple regex to match a percentage value range 1%-100%

Is there a better way to write this?

```
^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)%$
```

Comment: Why are you looking for a "better" way for such a simple problem? I mean problem solved, how much better than this can it get? 2 chars less, 4 less, who cares?

Comment: do you have any issues with this approach?

Comment: @Pop Catalin, if you can't offer an answer I don't need to hear the static. Just because something "solves" a problem doesn't mean maybe there isn't a "better" solution.

Comment: I like how this is only tagged as [regex]. "Regex is the only tool for the job!" Parse out the integer and use actual comparison operators on it.

Comment: @Macek, I like how you make assumptions based on nothing. Where did I say it's the only tool for any job, show me. I am using this with an xVal Validation. So I can't "parse the integer and blah blah blah...". This requires a regex solution, that's why I am asking for a regex solution.

Comment: @gmcalab, if a better solution is so important, what problems does the current solution have? (There's always a better solution to anything you can imagine, that doesn't mean, you should keep searching for solutions to one problem indefinitely)

Comment: @SilentGhost, when I get attacked as almost asking a stupid question I have a right to clarify their own stupidity.

Comment: @gmcalab, you could start by specifying the language you're working in. That gives people ways to potentially solve your problem from a whole new angle (other than just "regex"); possibly one you haven't even thought of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it a bit shorter:

```
^([1-9][0-9]?|100)%$
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the type of optimization I knew I was missing.

Comment: Here's a better one ([1-9]\d?|100)%$ it will make the OP even more happy: -2 chars.

Comment: it doesn't provide any measurable speed-up, though

Comment: @SilentGhost, that's ok though since the question wasn't (specifically) about  performance.

Comment: Yes I had no performance issue's just thought there might be a better approach.